# How to override the angular-material theme

Tags: angular-material

What is the best way to override the angular-material theme...?

Is it a good practice to override the angular-material classes, for example:

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
    background-color : #000fff;
}
```

or By creating own css classes for the Angular-material elements..?

By creating the own css classes, I'm facing the problem while selecting the inner child elements in the angular-material element.

[image: custom class]

Here I have created a custom class called "`form-filter-select-wrapper`", 
but I want to change the styling for the element with the class "`mat-form-field-infix`", which is parent element to the "`form-filter-select-wrapper`" class.

How can I customize the properties for this class "`mat-form-field-infix`". Which I can not handle from the component level.

Please advice me the best way to override the Angular-material elements.

Comment: hi Pavan i will help you with this please give me some more info how  you planning to change theme

Comment: Hi Harkesh Kumar, Thanks for your reply. I want to add the custom classes to the  auto-generated elements which are rendering in browser from the angular-material component.

Comment: can you start chat so i can help  properly

Comment: @harkeshkumar, Sorry I'm not able to find the chat link.. Can you please start the chat.

Comment: do one thing keep texting here then it will give you option to start

Comment: becus am not able to start chat yet

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/184479/how-to-override-the-angular-material-theme?tab=general

Comment: join chat clicking link

Comment: I joined harkeshkumar, But I have only read access can you provide the write access in the chat

Comment: let me check  give me minuts

Comment: your reputation is lass then 20 so not able to do it  Give me your email i will  talk to u

Comment: uidev3594@gmail.com

Comment: i sent  you email

Answer (score 3):

In my view, the best way to override a material theme is by creating a custom theme, as explained on the official documentation:

- [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)
- [Theming your custom component with Angular Material's theming system](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

The basics is to create a custom theme for the entire app, using default angular palettes/colors ([available here](https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0)), deciding between light or dark theme and letting it apply to the entire app.

Still, you may go much further, for example:

- Creating custom color palettes based on hex color codes
- Creating multiple themes and apply them to different components
- Theming components based on parent class